# SQLite3.Step (stmt) returns Error in Windows Runtime Apps

Tags: database, windows, sqlite, windows-runtime

I'm executing a **SELECT** query to retrieve data from SQLite database, but it doesn't return the required data. I don't know what error it is. I debugged and found that in `SQLite.cs` library, `SQLite3.Step(stmt)` is returning `Error` in this **while** statement `while(SQLite3.Step(stmt) == SQLite3.Result.Row)` instead of returning `Row`.

[image]

My query is: `SELECT FD.*, FT.CustomScriptBeforeLoad'TemplateScriptBeforeLoad', FT.CustomScriptAfterLoad'TemplateScriptAfterLoad', RT.Description AS RecordTypeDescription FROM FieldDefinitions FD INNER JOIN RecordTypes RT ON FD.RecordTypeId = RT.RecordTypeId JOIN FormTemplates FT ON FT.FormTemplateId = RT.FormTemplateId WHERE FT.FormTemplateId = 1871 AND (IFNULL(FD.IsHidden, '') != 'true' COLLATE NOCASE AND IFNULL(FD.CanView, '') != 'false' COLLATE NOCASE ) ORDER BY FD.SortOrder ASC`

I tried to execute the same query on my sqlite browser to see if the query is ok or not. But the query seems to be ok as it returns all values of 353 rows as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

**Update 1:**

I thought that the large number of rows might return `Error` in `SQLite3.Step(stmt)` so I decided to execute the same query which have **AND** condition.

`SELECT  FD.*, FT.CustomScriptBeforeLoad'TemplateScriptBeforeLoad', FT.CustomScriptAfterLoad'TemplateScriptAfterLoad', RT.Description AS RecordTypeDescription FROM FieldDefinitions FD INNER JOIN RecordTypes RT ON FD.RecordTypeId = RT.RecordTypeId JOIN FormTemplates FT ON FT.FormTemplateId = RT.FormTemplateId WHERE FT.FormTemplateId = 1871 AND (IFNULL(FD.IsHidden, '') != 'true' COLLATE NOCASE AND IFNULL(FD.CanView, '') != 'false' COLLATE NOCASE ) AND FieldDefinitionId >31000 ORDER BY FD.SortOrder ASC`

**And this query returns the 100 rows.** In my code this query executes very well as expected and returns the required values without giving `Error` in `SQLite3.Step(stmt)`.

[image]

Please suggest me what's the solution for this. Thanks in advance.